# Python check if line (two keywords) exists ignoring white spaces between

Tags: python, regex

My example file have a structure:

```
Library      Collections
Library      XML    use_lxml=True
Library      ute_wtssim
Library      libraries.ta_infomodel
Library      ute_tshark
Library      PDMLChecker.py
Library    libraries.ta_ue_configuration
Library      libraries.ta_tshark
Library    libraries.ta_file_system
Resource     environment_setup.robot
Variables    ../tshark_filters.py
Variables    ../global_variables.py
Variables    tracing_tshark_filters.py
```

I would like to find in file line: `Library      libraries.ta_infomodel` ignoring whitespaces (column width, which is not constant).

Could you give me advice?

EDIT:
I would like to check if line exist... 
Line which contains exactly two keywords, ignoring white spaces between.

Comment: `Library\s+libraries\.ta_infomodel`

Comment: If you know what it contains, why do you need to find it? And why would you use regex to find a static, known string?

Comment: You are right, my intention was to check if that line exists (ignoring white spaces between)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
content = """
Library      Collections
Library      XML    use_lxml=True
Library      ute_wtssim
Library      libraries.ta_infomodel
Library      ute_tshark
Library      PDMLChecker.py
Library      resources.DevWro1.pdml_validation.PdmlValidation
Library    libraries.ta_ue_configuration
Library      libraries.ta_tshark
Library    libraries.ta_file_system
Resource     environment_setup.robot
Variables    ../tshark_filters.py
Variables    ../global_variables.py
Variables    tracing_tshark_filters.py
"""

import re
regex = re.compile(r'Library\s+libraries\.ta_infomodel')
line = regex.search(content)
```

Some explanations. In order to find one line by a regex, you should use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), for many [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

`\s+` - for several spaces.

`\.` - for the dot. Use have to add the slash because just dot means any character.

Comment: What should I put in (content)? One line of the file or whole file which was opened? What would be better?

Comment: You don't have to feed it line by line. `content = myFile.read()` and after that `result = regex.search(content)`

Comment: Thank you for that response.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\s*`. `\s` stands for a whitespace. `*` means any number of (including zero):

```
import re
s = '''Library      Collections
Library      XML    use_lxml=True
Library      ute_wtssim
Library      libraries.ta_infomodel
Library      ute_tshark
Library      PDMLChecker.py
Library      resources.DevWro1.pdml_validation.PdmlValidation
Library    libraries.ta_ue_configuration
Library      libraries.ta_tshark
Library    libraries.ta_file_system
Resource     environment_setup.robot
Variables    ../tshark_filters.py
Variables    ../global_variables.py
Variables    tracing_tshark_filters.py'''

matches = re.findall('Library\s*libraries\.ta_infomodel', s)

for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: In your regex you forget back slash before the dot, so you may choose `Library librariesQta_infomodel`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Can be done with list comprehension too

```
import re
lines = open(fname, 'r').readlines()
found = [s for s in lines if re.match(".* Library\s+libraries\.ta_infomodel.*", s)]
```